# BlackBerry java UI development

Tags: blackberry

Is there a tool for BlackBerry java application UI development. I do not find drag and drop options in xml file in eclipse like in Android SDK. Is there something like Droid Draw here too? I am new to BB Java dev, any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Here are some links which were really helpful for me when I started doing BB UI. It would be hard for me to write a better answer than just repeating what these tutorials say, so I'll just give the links. Good luck!

Custom layout: http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=808
Custom fields: http://www.thinkingblackberry.com/archives/167
UI Threading: http://www.thinkingblackberry.com/archives/182

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no... There is no designer tool for blackberry ui, it must all be done in code. I heard that RIM plans on coming out with something of the kind but there is no such tool available at the moment.

There are tutorials on how to create many of the common UI, if you are searching for something specific I'm sure you can find some sample code to get you started.